# "ChromeDriver/ WebDriver can not be resoved to a type" error on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[openqa.selenium.WebDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JivNb.png)[openqa.selenium.chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuyDQ.png)[openqa.selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQcWG.png)[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspsI.png)[Java Build Path-> Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0az2.png)Need help! Using Selenium with Java for Chrome Browser on Eclipse.
It's a frequently asked question. Searched for all the solutions provided, but mine did not get resolved.

Have latest version:
Java: openjdk-15_windows-x64_bin
Eclipse: for Java Developers
Selenium WebDriver Java client: selenium-java-3.141.59
Google Chrome version: 86; chromedriver_win32 of the same version.

Trying to instantiate a new chrome driver:

Have added all the external jars coming from 'Selenium WebDriver Java client: selenium-java-3.141.59' to my project Java Buildpath -> Libraries -> Add External Jars.

My code:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    public class firstProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        
        WebDriver driver;           
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");  
        driver=new ChromeDriver();  
     
              
        }  
    }
```

Errors:
ChromeDriver can not be resolved to a type
WebDriver can not be resolved to a type

After adding the import statements, same error for all the three.
The import.org.----------  can not be resolved.

Please let me know what else to be done. I'm stuck, can not proceed.

Comment: The above issue mostly happens when Eclipse cannot find the required classes in your class path. Better to use build tools like maven to add dependencies. Could include screenshot of external jars you added for your project to better understand issue?

Comment: For Java 15 and Eclipse 2020-09 you have to install [Java 15 Support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417).

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the response. Installed Java 15 Support for Eclipse. Restarted eclipse, did not make any difference.

Comment: @VishalJagtap Thanks for the response. Added external jars in original post. Can you please check and let me know.

Comment: @RupaKondapalli You mean the same error is still shown. If you have an `module-info.java` file, delete it. If this does not help, show your project structure, where exactly the error is shown and the exact error message (and those of other errors, if they exist).

Comment: @howlger Yes, the same error is sown. No module-info.java file found. Please find the project structure and external jars attachecd in my original post. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @RupaKondapalli Where is the project structure? I cannot see it. Please show a screenshot of the _Package Explorer_ or _Project Explorer_ with expanded trees to show the source file and the missing classes (below the _Referenced Libraries_ node).

Comment: @howlger [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0az2.png)     [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspsI.png)

Comment: @RupaKondapalli [Your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspsI.png) shows below your project a _Referenced Libraries_ node that is collapsed. Expand it to the `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver` to prove you have added a JAR that contains this class.

Comment: @howlger [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9xm.png) please check this. I have added only the jars from Selenium-Java language binding. Pl

Comment: @RupaKondapalli That's expanded one level. Please also expand the JAR containing `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver` and expand further the `org.openqa.selenium.chrome` to show there is a `ChromeDriver` class. By the way, it looks now you have added a `module-info.java` to the default package. If so, delete this file.

Comment: @howlger Okay, I understood little bit now. Thanks. Expanded org.openqa.seleniu.chrome has ChromeDriver class. [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuyDQ.png) . I could not see another jar file with name org.openqa.seleniu.chrome.ChromeDriver. The org.openqa.selenium has the By class and the WebDriver class. [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQcWG.png) and [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JivNb.png). I have not added any module while creating the project, don't see the moudle-info.java file. May I know how you think the module-info.java is present in the default package.

Comment: @RupaKondapalli The error is now shown for `org.openqa` only. Maybe there is another JAR that contains the same package. In this case, you have to move the JARs from the Modulepath to the Classpath. Is there a reason to use Java 15? Please note, that the Java 15 support in Eclipse is not final and might have issues. Better use Java 8, 11 or 14 in Eclipse 2020-09 without the _Java 15 Support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)_ plugin. Is there something in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: @howlger Thank You. There was no specific reason to use Java 15, so uninstalled it and installed Java 14. Also did not check if any other JARs contain the same class/package, but moving the JARs to the Classpath from Modulepath worked. May be it would have worked with java 15 too, I will check that later. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @RupaKondapalli - Have set java path on your windows machine?

Comment: @VishalJagtap - Yes, with new installation of Java 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @howlger suggested: "Maybe there is another JAR that contains the same package. In this case, you have to move the JARs from the Modulepath to the Classpath."

Moving the JARs from Modulepath to Classpath removed the errors and I was able to open chrome webpage.